# Linux OS installed as a guest OS on VMware Workstation v10.0.2 doesn't show all partitions as is shown when installed ona physical HP server

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, partition, vmware-esx, vmware-workstation

I'm very new to VMWARE. I've a customized RHEL 6.6 for one of my application which if install on a physical HP Gen8 DL380p server, shows the partitions /apps, /,/boot,/tmp,/var,/usr,/swap

When I use the same ISO to install on VMware Workstation 10.0.2, the OS loads up without any errors, but my partition shows only /,/boot,/swap

Why is this happening. How can I reflect all the above partitions on the guest OS on VM as well?

Answer (score 0):

Do an `ls -al /` you will see the directories are still there. Unless you have setup the install to move these mount points to separate mount points they should be still on the main partition.

You can compare `/etc/fstab` `fdisk -l` and `df -h` to look at mount points and their logical disks. Typical setups of vmware guests only have one drive where physical servers will have multiple.